# Uncaught TypeError: getOptionLabel Prop is not a function getting this error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

// Initialize useState
const [selectedNames, setSelectedNames] = useState([]);

```
//Array format
    const subLocationData = [{
        0: "Intent1",
        1: "Intent2",
        2: "Intent3"
      }]
    
// This is HTML
    <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="fixed-tags-demo"
        value={selectedNames}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => 
         {setSelectedNames([...newValue.filter((option) => option)]);}}
        options={subLocationData}
        getOptionLabel={subLocationData.map(option => option)}
        renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
          tagValue.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip
              label={option}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}                      
            />
          ))
        }
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label={formData.location.value} placeholder={formData.location.value} />
        )}
    />
```

I'm adding searching dropdown with the help of metarial UI Autocomplete but my array format which is coming from API is different from the format of their array.
So, that is why I'm getting this error. Please help me how can I resolve this. It is critical.

Comment: The error is that the value of the `getOptionLabel` prop isn't a function. You're setting it here: `getOptionLabel={subLocationData.map(option => option)}`. The result of `map` is an array, not a function. (There's also no point in `.map(option => option)`, you're just making a copy of the array; if you want to create an array copy, use `[...subLocationData]` or `subLocationData.slice()` or similar, rather than using `map` for a non-mapping operation.)

Comment: That is also not working. And my concern is how do I use my array in "getOptionLabel"  and show it's value in dropdown

Comment: The `map` thing was a side-comment. The fundamental issue, as the error message says and as I pointed out above, is that you need to supply a **function**, not an array, for that prop. But you're providing an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, In this I've added a transformedSubLocationData array that is created by mapping over your original subLocationData array and converting each element into an object with label and value properties

```
const subLocationData = [
  "Intent1",
  "Intent2",
  "Intent3"
];

// Transforming the array into the required format
const transformedSubLocationData = subLocationData.map((label, index) => ({
  label,
  value: index.toString()  // You can use the index as the value or any unique identifier
}));

// Rest of your code
<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="fixed-tags-demo"
  value={selectedNames}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setSelectedNames([...newValue.filter((option) => option)]);
  }}
  options={transformedSubLocationData}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
  renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
    tagValue.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        label={option.label}
        {...getTagProps({ index })}
      />
    ))
  }
  style={{ width: 500 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label={formData.location.value} placeholder={formData.location.value} />
  )}
/>
```